Issues with Diacritical Characters in SQL Query Using FreeTDS and pyodbc on Rocky Linux 8
I am encountering a problem with SQL queries containing diacritical characters while using FreeTDS and pyodbc to connect to a Sybase database on different server environments. Here are the details:
Environment 1:

OS: CentOS 6
FreeTDS Version: freetds-0.91-2.el6.x86_64
Python
Library: pyodbc 4.0.34

Environment 2:

OS: Rocky Linux 8
FreeTDS Version: freetds-1.3.3-1.el8.x86_64 and freetds-libs-1.3.3-1.el8.x86_64
Python Library: pyodbc 4.0.34

Issue:

The same Python script, which executes an SQL query containing diacritical characters, works correctly on the CentOS 6 server when run against the same database.
On the Rocky Linux 8 server, the script fails with the following error:

('42000', "[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unclosed quote before the character string ','.\n (105) (SQLExecDirectW)")


If I remove the diacritical characters but keep the rest of the comment, the SQL query executes correctly on the Rocky Linux 8 server.

Below is the content of the file /etc/freetds.conf on the Rocky Linux 8 server:
#
# This file is installed by FreeTDS if no file by the same
# name is found in the installation directory.
#
# For information about the layout of this file and its settings,
# see the freetds.conf manpage "man freetds.conf".

# Global settings are overridden by those in a database
# server specific section
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
        tds version = auto

        # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
        # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
;       dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;       debug flags = 0xffff

        # Command and connection timeouts
;       timeout = 10
;       connect timeout = 10

        # To reduce data sent from server for BLOBs (like TEXT or
        # IMAGE) try setting 'text size' to a reasonable limit
;       text size = 64512

        # If you experience TLS handshake errors and are using openssl,
        # try adjusting the cipher list (don't surround in double or single quotes)
        # openssl ciphers = HIGH:!SSLv2:!aNULL:-DH

# A typical Sybase server
[egServer50]
        host = symachine.domain.com
        port = 5000
        tds version = 5.0

# A typical Microsoft server
[egServer73]
        host = ntmachine.domain.com
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.3

Here's the content of the file /etc/freetds.conf on the CentOS 6 server:
#   $Id: freetds.conf,v 1.12 2007/12/25 06:02:36 jklowden Exp $
#
# This file is installed by FreeTDS if no file by the same
# name is found in the installation directory.
#
# For information about the layout of this file and its settings,
# see the freetds.conf manpage "man freetds.conf".

# Global settings are overridden by those in a database
# server specific section
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
;       tds version = 4.2

        # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
        # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
;       dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;       debug flags = 0xffff

        # Command and connection timeouts
;       timeout = 10
;       connect timeout = 10

        # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
        # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.
        # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit
        text size = 64512

# A typical Sybase server
[egServer50]
        host = symachine.domain.com
        port = 5000
        tds version = 5.0

# A typical Microsoft server
[egServer70]
        host = ntmachine.domain.com
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.0

Section from the /etc/odbcinst.ini file:
[TDS-ASE]
Description=Sybase ODBC TDS Driver
Driver=/usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
Setup=/usr/lib64/libtdsS.so.2
TDS_Version=5
UsageCount=3
CPTimeout=
CPReuse=

Has anyone experienced similar issues or can suggest a solution to ensure the query with diacritical characters works correctly on Rocky Linux 8? Any insights on the differences in FreeTDS configurations that might be causing this would be highly appreciated.

Where's the code for the pyodbc connection string? The freetds.conf file on CentOS 6 would be helpful as well. It sounds like you might have an explicit TDS Version configured on the CentOS 6 box (perhaps for v7.4), but not on the Rocky 8 box.

Connection string: DRIVER={TDS-ASE};SERVER=syb-server;PORT=5000;DATABASE=tests;UID=patching;PWD=*******. I include the freetds.conf file from CentOS 6 server in issue's description above.

You might want to include that you're connecting to Sybase / SAP, not SQL Server. The vast majority of FreeTDS and pyodbc usage is to connect to SQL Server. Also, you may not be using FreeTDS. The typical configure for FreeTDS is DRIVER={FreeTDS}, which must match the entry in /etc/odbcinst.ini header (which would be [FreeTDS]). Is it possible you're using an alternate driver?

In the /etc/odbcinst.ini file there is section with header [TDS-ASE]. Sql without diacritical characters works correctly.

I think the issue may be using two different drivers on the two different systems. Check the values in /etc/odbcinst.ini on both systems. The one you included seems to point to a driver that might not be FreeTDS, specifically because you're specifying TDS_Version=5, which may not support UTF-8 characters. The path matches a typical FreeTDS install at /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0, but the description doesn't match a typical FreeTDS install.

Do you have the TDS_Version=5 in /etc/odbcinst.ini on both of the servers? Are the odbcinst.ini, odbc.ini and freetds.conf files identical on both?
